# Elasticsearch query to return all record programmatically throws out of memory exception

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to retrieve all records from elasticsearch and do statistical analysis on the data. The number of records are not that high 500000 records. Each record has 7 columns, 5 of these columns are type String (single word value). So the size of data to me is not that big at all. I am getting 'out of memory exception' when executing the following:

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(indexFrom).setTypes(typeFrom)
            .setQuery(matchAllQuery()).setSize(SIZE)
            .execute().actionGet();
SIZE=500000
```

Any help/suggestions?
I am setting Xmx10g.

Thanks.
-Vera

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to recover all documents unsorted like this, you should use a **[scan and scroll](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scan-scroll.html)** search.

To sum up, it combines the use of :

- search of type scan which disable sorting of results (thus save some memory)
- scroll API which is quite similar to a cursor for DB by allowing you to look through results by small batches.

I think it could solve your memory problem.